# Issues while running AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to run AVD with newly installed Android Studio. I have an AMD Ryzen processor, who I downloaded the ARM API.

I still get an error
minSdk(api27) > devSdk(api25)

I learnt that I need to make changes in the build.gradle file.
when I opened it. It already had the settings as below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rahul.myfirstandroidapplication"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

please help

Answer (score 1):

Your min SDK in the gradle file should be 25 or lower if you want to run the application on this AVD or you should create another AVD with different SDK version.